# How do I call a method of a generic type object?

Tags: java, generics

The below code gives me the error:

```
SceneNode.java:17: cannot find symbol
symbol  : method execute() location:
class java.lang.Object
                operation.execute();
                         ^ 1 error
```

Code:

```
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.Iterator;

public class SceneNode<T>{
    T operation;    
    public SceneNode() {
    }   
    public SceneNode(T operation) {
        this.operation = operation;
    }
    public void setOperation(T operation) {
        this.operation = operation;
    }
    public void doOperation() {
        operation.execute();
    }
}
```

It's a cut down (for your readability) start of a simple scene graph. The node could be a model, transformation, switch, etc., so I made a variable called `operation` that's type is defined by the `T` class variables. This way I can pass a `Transformation` / `Model` / `Switch` object (that has an `execute` method) and pass it like this:

```
SceneNode<Transformation> = new SceneNode<Transformation>(myTransformation);
```

I'm pretty sure having a base class of `SceneNode` and subclassing for all the various types of nodes would be a better idea (I was trying out generics, only learnt about them recently). Why doesn't this work? I must be missing something fundamental about generics.

Answer (score 14):

It doesn't work because `T` could be *any* type, and Java is statically typed. The compiler has no idea whether you'll try to create a `SceneNode<String>` - then what would `execute` do?

One option is to create an appropriate interface, e.g.

```
public interface Executable {
    void execute();
}
```

and then to constrain `T` in `SceneNode` to implement `Executable`:

```
public class SceneNode<T extends Executable> {
    ...
}
```

(I find it a little bit odd that `T` has to *extend* `Executable` rather than *implement* it in the source code, but then `T` could end up being an interface itself, so I guess it makes sense.)

Then it should work fine. Of course you *could* make `Executable` an abstract superclass instead - or even a (non-final) concrete class - if you wanted, but I would generally prefer to use an interface unless I had some reason not to.

Comment: @dty: Yup, I was already on it. Looks weird to me, but such is Java generics :(

Comment: sorry,  but why is it not    ___implements Executable___?

Comment: @LukAron: Because that's just not the syntax used for generic type bounds. See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se10/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.4. I understand it's a little odd, but it does make it consistent.

Answer (score 10):

I'm guessing you come from a C++ background.

The compiler has no idea what kind of a thing T might be because you haven't told it.

If you had an interface called, for example, `Executable` which defines your `execute()` method, then you would need to do:

```
public class SceneNode<T extends Executable> {
    // ... 
}
```

Now, the compiler will know that T is an `Executable`, and will give you access to all the methods on that interface.

Comment: Because a generic <T> is actually an `Object` for Java (is the same as <T extends Object>), until a base class is specified <T extends BaseClass>

Comment: Thankyou, that's solved it and I now understand why as well. I had seen that syntax before but i thought it meant "object must be a subclass of this object". Which seems silly in hindsight.

Comment: @Callum: It means "the parameter type must be a subtype of the given type", thus you now can only use subtypes of Executable for T.

Comment: I come from c++ and actually find it hard to get too, so thanks for this explanation. It's a bit weird though, I would guess that the compiler should look for usages of a generic class to see if a method called is actually there - that's how it's done in c++. Having to specify a class that T extends from kind of diminishes usability of a generic class, it's not generic anymore - it's only for the objects extending this class, right? Anyway, I think I need to study this topic a bit more.

Answer (score 5):

Recently I came across a situation where I had to call a method on generic object. Getting reflection in action worked for me.

```
public class SceneNode<T>{
    T operation;    
    public SceneNode() {
    }   
    public SceneNode(T operation) {
        this.operation = operation;
    }
    public void setOperation(T operation) {
        this.operation = operation;
    }
    public void doOperation() {
        Method m = operation.getClass().getMethod("execute");
        m.invoke(operation);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Java is statically typed language. You must know the type at compile-time in order to be able to invoke a method. Instead of a subclass you can have an interface `Executable` that defines the `execute()` method. `T` (without any `<T extends SomeClass>`) has only the methods defined by `java.lang.Object`.