# make common method for different data querying

Tags: java

Suppose I have similar methods that does almost same thing How do I make it one method that will query different data. Here only the dataManager querying data is different and gets different Object Lists for iteration.

```
private void method1(ClassA classA){
    List<One> one = dataManager.getOne(classA.param1);
    if (one != null){
        //iterate data here...
       for (int i = 0; i < one.size(); i++)
       {
           one.get(i).getAttributeOne();
           one.get(i).getAttributeTwo();
       }
    }else{
    }
}

private void method2(ClassA classA){
    List<Two> two = dataManager.getTwo(classA.param1);
    if (two != null){
        //iterate data here...
    }else{
    }
}
```

Comment: 1. How are the classes `One` and `Two` related? Are they both, e.g., extending the same abstract class? Or are they unrelated classes? 2. Can you determine which class you are retrieving based on `classA.param1?

Comment: they are not related. but those are JPA entities.

Comment: @Swarnajith is the `iterate data here...` part exactly the same ?

Comment: in there setting values. its almost similar, so yes

Comment: @Swarnajith "almost similar" is not good enough :) Because this could make answers that use generics valid (if just the types are different) or invalid if there's an actual (even a small) difference that one cannot overcome using a template parameter. It would be better if you posted the real code...

Comment: lets say its the same depending on object type which we retrieve

Comment: @Swarnajith awesome so IMHO templates is the way to go as in merlin2011's [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24271457/1941161).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do the call to `dataManager.get()` in the calling method, and use generics to handle the different list types.

```
private <T> void method1(ClassA classA, List<T> myList){
    if (myList != null){
        //iterate data here...
    }else{
    }
}

// Calling code
method1(myClassA, dataManager.getOne(myClassA.param1));
method1(myClassA, dataManager.getTwo(myClassA.param1));
```

Here is a compilable example that looks like what you are trying to solve.

```
import java.util.*;

public class Iterate{
    private <T> void method1(int classA, List<T> L){
        for (T t: L) {
            System.out.println(t);
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
       List<Integer> iList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
       List<String> sList = new ArrayList<String>();
       new Iterate().method1(1, iList);
       new Iterate().method1(1, sList);
    }
}
```

Comment: @Swarnajith, You will have to be more specific, but the general answer is that yes, you can make a Java interface generic.

Comment: how about making a interface that implements JPA Entity(One, Two etc.)

Comment: @Swarnajith, I am not familiar with `JPA`. I recommend asking a new question and tagging it appropriately. You can link back to this one for more context.

Comment: @Swarnajith, Also, `interface` does not implement anything. Other classes implement `interface`.

Comment: I have added the way of iterating the elements, but according to your solution its asking to Cast the Object type for iterated element. How do I overcome that issue?

Comment: @Swarnajith, Take a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5129685/java-call-a-method-on-an-object-that-had-its-type-defined-by-a-class-variable). You can use the solution there if there is a common base class with the methods you require. If not, then you will have to condition on the type and call different methods inside the loop.