# Templates and Generics. Why can I do the following in C++ but not in Java? How do I overcome this?

Tags: java, c++, templates, generics

Consider the following C++ program:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template<typename T>
class example
{
    public:
    void function (T a)
    {
        std::cout<<a.size ();
    }
};

int main() {
    example<string> a; // this doesn't
    string b = "a";
    //example<int> a; This gives an error
    a.function (b);
    // your code goes here
    return 0;
}
```

And now consider the following Java program:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

class example<T> {

    public void function (T a)
    {
        System.out.println (a.toHexString(5)); /* this does not compile even when T is Integer */
    }


}

public class  Main
{
    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        example<Integer> a = new example<Integer> (); 
        Integer b = 2;
        a.function(b);

        return;
    }
}
```

I have majorly been a C++ developer until now and am learning Java for job purposes. So, coming from a background having worked with templates, generics confuse me.

Coming to my question:

In the above C++ code, the code compiles and runs fine if I pass string as template parameter because string does have a size () method. If I used int as a template parameter, I would've gotten an error, understandably. The point to note here is that C++ lets me compile and run the code if I pass a template parameter that has a method called size().

However, in the Java code, even when I pass Integer as the generic parameter (? is that a term?) which DOES have toHexString(int) method, the program still does not compile. It returns an error:

```
cannot find symbol
```

What's the issue here? What prevents me in Java from achieving this behaviour?

Edit: The question was marked as a possible duplicate for another question:
[How do I call a method of a generic type object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5129685/java-call-a-method-on-an-object-that-had-its-type-defined-by-a-class-variable) 
I'll copy paste my response to why I think the question's different.
The above question 'potentially' tells me how to get rid of the error. What I'm asking is what prevents me in Java from achieving the above effect? The said question gives me the medicine of the disease, not the cause.

I raised a similar question on ##java and heard of a new term - reification. I was wondering if it had anything to do with this?

Comment: @Dukeling: Not exactly. The above question 'potentially' tells me how to get rid of the error. What I'm asking is what prevents me in Java from doing so? The said question gives me the medicine of the disease, not the cause.

Comment: The line you marked is not the line that causes the error.

Comment: @NikharAgrawal IMO the answers there explain the problem and fix well enough (but others are free to disagree). As to why Java actually works that way - this was just a language design decision (and I assume it would be anyone's guess as to why this was decided).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Java generics are implemented via *type erasure*. When you have a class signature like this:

```
class example<T> { }
```

.. The class is compiled as a regular Java class. For this, T effectively takes on the type of its upper bound, in this case `Object`. If you have a method such as the function in your example, with a parameter of type `T`:

```
    public void function (T a)
```

... Then this is, at the point that this function is compiled, almost the same as having the parameter be of type `Object`. As such, you can't call a method such as `toHexString` on the parameter, because that method is not defined in `Object`.

In C++ on the other hand, a lot of symbol resolution happens when the template is instantiated rather than when it is first compiled. This is the key difference; in Java, a generic class is compiled to bytecode, and so method calls etc must be resolved when the generic class is compiled (that is, the compiler must be able to decide what class or interface the method comes from). In C++, when the compiler encounters a template, it does not try to resolve references or produce object code unless and until the template is instantiated.

Another way to think about it: in Java, `example<String>` and `example<Integer>` are both implemented via the same class. In C++, they would be two separate classes (both which result from instantiation of the template).

This is, in fact, why Java generic classes are not "templates". In C++, a class *template* allows to instantiate classes (i.e. it serves as a template from which to create classes). In Java, a generic class allows for parametrized types to be implemented by a *single* class.

A Java generic class can be considered to be quite similar to a non-generic class with the type parameters (eg `T`) being replaced with the bound type (`Object` unless otherwise specified) - the main difference being that the compiler will perform additional type checking when you call methods on an instance of the class (which has a full type with type arguments, such that `T` maps to some other type), and will effectively insert casts (so that you can call a method which returns a `T`, via a reference where `T` is mapped to some type, without having to cast the return type).

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that Java generics is nothing like C++ templates and was never designed to be so. Java generics was designed with one specific target - to add strong type checking at compile time. As such you will find the following an approximation to your Java version.

```
interface Hex {

    public String toHexString(int length);
}

class Example<T extends Hex> {

    public void function(T a) {
        System.out.println(a.toHexString(5));
    }

}

class StringWithHex implements Hex {

    @Override
    public String toHexString(int length) {
        return "Hex";
    }

}

public void test() {
    Example<StringWithHex> e = new Example<>();
    e.function(new StringWithHex());
}
```

See how it is only ensuring that types match.