# Sending a List of different objects and returning the sum of their properties

Tags: java

I have to classes

```
public class Consumer{


private String name;
private int salary;


public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public int getSalary() {
    return salary;
}

public void setSalary(int salary) {
    this.salary = salary;
}
}
```

and next

```
public class Donor {

private String name;
private int amount;
private String location;



public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public int getAmount() {
    return amount;
}

public void setAmount(int amount) {
    this.amount = amount;
}
}
```

now i have another class which contains a method method1()

```
public class GenericClass<T> {

    public void method1(List<T> list){

        Iterator i = list.iterator();

        while (i.hasNext()){

        }
    }


}
```

and My main method is

```
public class MainMethod {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Donor> d = new ArrayList<>();


        Donor donor = new Donor();
        donor.setAmount(500);
        donor.setName("bill");


        Donor donor1 = new Donor();
        donor.setAmount(1250);
        donor.setName("linda");

        d.add(donor);
        d.add(donor1);


        GenericClass genericClass = new GenericClass();
        genericClass.method1(d);
    }




}
```

i want to make this method1() dynamic and return a dynamic result.

so if i send the list of Consumer then it should return me the sum of all salaries and if i send the list of Donor then it should send me the sum of amount donated ?

how can this be achieved ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I call a method of a generic type object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5129685/how-do-i-call-a-method-of-a-generic-type-object)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First, you'd probably not make the class `GenericClass` generic but the method `method1()`.

Then you could provide a `ToIntFunction<T>` which takes an object of type `T` and returns an `int` value. Thus your method could look like this (Java8 code):

```
public <T> int method1(List<T> list, ToIntFunction<T> transformation){  
  return list.stream().collect(Collectors.summingInt(transformation));      
}
```

You'd then call that method like this:

```
int sumSalaries = method1(consumers, Consumer::getSalary);
int sumDonations = method1(donors, Donor::getAmount);
```

Pre-Java8 code would be possible as well but it would be a little bigger (you'd need to provide `ToIntFunction`, implementations of that interface and a slightly larger method body).

Alternatively you could use an Interface that's implemented by both classes but that would require you to use a common method name (e.g. `getAmount()` or `getIntValue()` etc.)